# Is it possible to add shadow without elevation or elevation without shadow on android?

Tags: android, react-native

for react-native on android,

I wanna add either shadow without using elevation or elevation without shadow(shadow-color).

Is there any way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated!
Danke!

Answer (score 1):

As React-Native Shadow Props only work in IOS there is no alternative of using elevation.
But you can use a **react-native-shadow** as an alternative of elevation.